# IIS website authorization failure

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, iis-7

I have mapped the WWWRoot folder on D: drive and also enabled the shared configuration in IIS7, the physical path 'Test Settings' says the Authentication is successful, but the authorization says "Path might not exist and could not be verified (D:\wwwroot)".

Details: The path does not exist or environm
ent variables in the path could not be expanded to verify whether it exists.

P.S: The D: drive is created using SUBST command which maps a folder on C: Drive as a separate drive. I don't understand what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subst` is a command-line shortcut that applies only to your interactive session. Other users on the computer (including the system user that the IIS service will be running as) won't see any D: drive.

If you really must expose a directory as a different drive then try the DosDevices registry hack outlined in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots).

Comment: I understand this about subst command, but my problem is about the IIS website not recognising the path, as the wwwroot is in that virtual drive.

Comment: @samee: It isn't a virtual drive. It's a shortcut only accessible to commands in your current session, which IIS isn't, so it will never recognise any such path. You will need to use a different mechanism.